# Is this question considered as localized?

Tags: discussion

This is the question from a new user asking [Is Sher-Wood T90 considered a pro stock hockey stick?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16811/is-sher-wood-t90-considered-a-pro-stock-hockey-stick), I edited the question correcting spelling but realized that it may be localized and if it is so, what can we do to this question. And if this question is not localized, what are the reason that makes it so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, note that "too localized" is [no longer a close reason on the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons).

That said, if the question is essentially asking "Is the Sher-Wood T90 available from [ProStockHockey](https://www.prostockhockey.com/)?" (which I *think* it is, although it's not entirely clear) then I do think it's off-topic - the place to ask this question is ProStockHockey's customer support, not Stack Exchange. While the T90 may be available today from ProStockHockey, that's going to change and the question will be useless a year or two from now.

The other possibility is that the question is asking "Is the Sher-Wood T90 considered a professional *quality* hockey stick?" (with a bad translation of "quality" - the poster's location is listed as Germany, so it's likely their first language isn't English). The question I'd say is off-topic as opinion based, but it's saved by the secondary question in the body ("Do some NHL players use it?") as that's something that can be factually answered.

I was going to say that I'd ask the poster for clarification on what they meant, but you've already done that so thank you for that :-)

At the moment, I'd be tempted to close this as "unclear what you're asking" due to the uncertainty about what the question is actually meaning, but I'm not going to use a moderator binding vote to do that (and unfortunately moderators can't just vote to close as an ordinary user - it's all or nothing when we vote). Over to you, community.